Бот, воспроизводящий музыку в голосовом канале Discord
Я пытаюсь создать дискорд-бота, который будет входить в голосовой канал и воспроизводить звук с видео youtube. Код на вход в голосовой канал я уже написал, а воспроизведение музыки не знаю как сделать
@bot.slash_command(description="Воспроизведение музыки")
async def play(inter, url: str):
    channel = inter.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    if inter.guild.voice_client:
        pass
    else:
        await inter.send("Вы не подключены к ГС")


Добро пожаловать на сайт, AstroPowerX, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой, как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В данный момент воспроизвести видео с ютуба невозможно из-за ограничений. Попробуй использовать сторонние сервисы для воспроизведения музыки(VK Music, Yandex Music и др.)
